# Foreman and exporting execution of ruby file to upstart

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, foreman, upstart

I am fairly new to the use of foreman on a production environment setup and wanted to see if perhaps someone could offer some needed insight.

I currently am using foreman to run a a simple pure ruby app within a rails app I have. I can get this to work just fine locally by simply going foreman start which then runs a simple script of

ruby /relative_path_to_ruby_file

This works fine however when exporting to upstart, it seems a relative path does not properly execute the file and thus here I am.

Is there a convention to using foreman to run ruby  that I am unaware of? As said before I was just using relative path to the procfile, but what would be the path needed to have it be executable by upstart?

I tried explicitly pointing to the file like

ruby /home/deploy/apps/app_name/current/program/boot.rb

however this also seemed to fail in properly running that file. What is the normal convention for trying to run a file in the manner I am here? Is it a matter of me just giving the paths incorrectly?

if it helps to know, I am currently running ubuntu 12.04